# How to display 0 instead of empty cell when browsing a cube in ssas without using mdx?

Tags: ssas, business-intelligence, olap-cube

I need to display 0 instead of empty cell when browsing a cube in excel. I used mdx functions like: `IIF(ISEMPTY(Measure) = True , 0, Measure)` but, i don't like this solution. I need to find, if there is another solution more simple than this one. If someone knows please share the information.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your client tool, you could get along with using the format string for the measure. If you would e. g. use `"0;;;0"` or `"#,##0;;;0"` as the format string, then empty (i. e. `null`) values would use the part after the third semicolon, which is `0`, for display.

A detailed documentation of the `format_string` can be found at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146084.aspx. And the possibility to use the format string is just offered by Analysis Services to the client tool accessing the cube, and the tool itself - actually, its developers - decides if it uses that or the raw numeric value instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the COALESCEEMPTY(Measure, 0) function of MDX. It works in the same manner as COALESCE in SQL and returns the first non empty value.